# Axios custom deserialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

Is it possible to do (preferably partial) custom deserialization of an Axios call response (in React with Typescript)? I have a class that extends the JS Array (of T), but when I use Axios's native deserialization, I get a standard array, which I do not want.

Example:

```
interface MyData {
    arrayInData: MyArray<string>
    // Rest of interface omitted
}
```

and

```
class MyArray Extends Array<T> { ... } //Implementation omitted
```

and

```
async function LoadData(): Promise<MyData>
{
    const response = await axios.get(/* url */);

    return response.data;
}
```

This returns an object of type MyData, but MyData.arrayInData is of type Array, not MyArray.

Is there a way to do either

1. (Preferably) A partial custom deserialization? Something like

   ```
   async function LoadData(): Promise<MyData>
   {
       const response = await axios.get(/* url */);

       return response.useAxiosMapButChangeArrayToMyArray(data => /* code to only take arrayInData and make it a MyArray and leave the rest as Axios's standard automatic deserialization */ );
   }
   ```
2. A "complete" custom map where I can do something like

   ```
   async function LoadData(): Promise<MyData>
   {
       const response = await axios.get(/* url */);

       return response.MapEverything(data => new {
           arrayInData = new MyArray<string>(data.arrayInData)
           // rest of class
       });
   }
   ```